# Problem processing multi-part .rar files with parity archive tool in Ruby

Tags: ruby, batch-file

Using the parity archive creation tool par2j64.exe, I wrote a script in Ruby that  creates parity archives for single .rar files but want to be able to use it for multi-part .rar files too.

This works for single .rar files:

```ruby
# Set parameters for par2j64
parity_tool = "par2j64.exe"
redundancy_percent = "15"
par2_files = "8"
working_directory = "G:/Working"

# Find all RAR files in the specified working directory
rar_files = Dir.glob(File.join(working_directory, "*.rar"))

if rar_files.empty?
puts "No RAR files found in the specified working directory."
else
# Iterate over each RAR file
rar_files.each do |rar_file_path|
# Extract the filename from the file path
rar_file_name = File.basename(rar_file_path)

# Create parity archives for the RAR file
puts "Creating parity archives for #{rar_file_name}..."
Dir.chdir(working_directory) do
  system("#{parity_tool} c /rr#{redundancy_percent} /rf#{par2_files} /rd1 \"#{rar_file_name}.par2\" \"#{rar_file_path}\"")
end
puts "Parity archives created for #{rar_file_name}."
puts
end
end
```

This DOS script code works, but I can't figure out how to convert it to a Ruby script:

```batch-file
rem Search the first file of each splitted RAR archive
for %%F in ("*.part1.rar" "*.part01.rar" "*.part001.rar") do (
    call :SUB_CREATE "%%~nF"
)

echo Parity archive creation complete.
pause

rem Exit script before sub routine
exit

:SUB_CREATE
rem Sub-routine to create PAR files for multiple input files

echo Creating parity archives for multiple %~n1...
%PARITY_TOOL% c /rr%REDUNDANCY_PERCENT% /rf%PAR2_FILES% /rd1 "%~n1.par2" "%~n1.part*.rar"
echo Parity archives created for multiple %~n1.
echo
rem exit subroutine
exit /B
```

I've tried things like this in Ruby that didn't work:

```ruby
# Set parameters
parity_tool = "par2j64.exe"
redundancy_percent = "15"
par2_files = "8"
working_directory = "G:/Working"

# Search the first file of each splitted RAR archive
Dir.glob("*.part1.rar") do |file|
create_parity(file)
end

Dir.glob("*.part01.rar") do |file|
create_parity(file)
end

Dir.glob("*.part001.rar") do |file|
create_parity(file)
end

puts "Parity archive creation complete."
puts "Press Enter to continue."
gets

# Method to create parity archives for multiple input files
def create_parity(file)
puts "Creating parity archives for multiple #{File.basename(file, ".*")}..."
system("#{parity_tool} c /rr#{redundancy_percent} /rf#{par2_files} /rd1 #{File.basename(file, ".*")}.par2 #{File.basename(file, ".*")}.part*.rar")
puts "Parity archives created for multiple #{File.basename(file, ".*")}."
puts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out myself. I had tried something like this earlier but couldn't see why it wasn't working. The problem was that the ".part" in a multi-part .rar file was being included as part of the base filename and so then par2j64.exe wasn't finding the input file. The following Ruby script worked to create parity archives for muti-part .rar files it assumes that the path to par2j64.exe has been added to the Windows environmental variable or else one would need to call it including the actual path:

```
directory = "."  # Specify the directory where the files           are located

# Search for the .rar files in the directory
rar_files = Dir.glob(File.join(directory, "*.rar"))

if rar_files.empty?
  puts "No .rar files found in the directory."
  exit
end

# Extract the base filename from the first .rar file found
# and split off the .part because it can't be part of the
# base_filename when sent to par2j64
base_filename = File.basename(rar_files.first, ".*")
base_filename_without_parts = base_filename.split(".part").first

# Create the input file pattern
input_files = "#{base_filename_without_parts}.part*.rar"


# Set the output file name
output_file = "#{base_filename_without_parts}.par2"

command = "par2j64.exe c /rr15 /rf8 /rd1 \"#{output_file}\" \"#{input_files}\""
system(command)
```